# How can I find the version number of an installed package via dpkg?

Tags: command-line, dpkg

I use the `dpkg -l` command to find out what version of a package I have installed. For example:

```
dpkg -l network-manager
```

returns the information on the package:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                      Version                   Description
+++-=========================-=========================-==================================================================
ii  network-manager           0.8.3~git.20101118t223039 network management framework daemon
```

As you can see, it returns `0.8.3~git.20101118t223039` which is wrong because it truncates the version (I've picked a long one for the purpose of this question). The way I've solved this in the past is to pass a stupidly long COLUMNS argument to make it expand:

```
COLUMNS=200 dpkg -l network-manager
```

which gives me the entire version number, but also a bunch of junk:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                         Version                                      Description
+++-============================================-============================================-========================================================================================================
ii  network-manager                              0.8.3~git.20101118t223039.d60a988-0ubuntu1   network management framework daemon
```

Now I can see the full version number, which is `0.8.3~git.20101118t223039.d60a988-0ubuntu1`.

I get the feeling that this is not the proper way to find the version number of an installed package. This never really was a problem in the past, but with the tacking on of "ubuntu" in the versions and the proliferation of PPAs these strings are getting longer and longer. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
dpkg -s <packagename> | grep '^Version:'
```

e. g.:

```
dpkg -s network-manager | grep '^Version:'
```

Sample output:

```
Version: 0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2
```

Comment: `dpkg --info package.deb` works, though `-s` didn't

Comment: @Twisted Pear - `dpkg --info package.deb` operates on package files, `dpkg -s <packagename>` operates on package names - no file required

Comment: for completeness: `dpkg -s sepio.agent | grep -i '^Version' | cut -d' ' -f2`

Answer (score 67):

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}' --show python3-lxml
```

Comment: When querying multiple packages I suggest: `dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\t${Version}\n' --show lsb-release coreutils ...`

Comment: I like this version, since it is precise (not grep or cut needed).

Comment: Almost certainly want to print a newline, otherwise this is "printf"-like behaviour. For example, `dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}\n' --show python3-lxml`.

Answer (score 26):

It's not using the `dpkg` command but [apt-show-versions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt-show-versions) [image: Install banshee]

Example:

```
$ apt-show-versions network-manager  
network-manager/maverick uptodate 0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2
```

Comment: this isn't available in Mint 20, in case anyone else needs to know that

Answer (score 16):

I think aneeshep's is the best answer as your question specifies using dpkg. But for completeness sake, here's another way:

```
apt-cache policy network-manager 
network-manager:
  Installed: 0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Or for just the version number:

```
apt-cache policy network-manager | grep 'Installed:' | cut -c 14-
0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2
```

Comment: The output of `apt-cache` depends on the current Locale.  For example in Germany you need to `grep 'Installiert:'`.  To compensate for that, always use Locale `C.UTF-8` when scripting.  Either with `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8; export LC_ALL` at the start of the script or for a case-by-case basis something like: `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 apt-cache policy network-manager | grep 'Installed:' | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 7):

Another method to find the version of an installed package via `dpkg` as below,

```
dpkg -l | awk '$2=="package-name" { print $3 }'
```

**Example:**

```
$ dpkg -l | awk '$2=="network-manager" { print $3 }'
0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
```

**Explanation:**

`dpkg -l` command lists all the installed packages.This standard output was fed as input to the `awk` command.`awk` searches for the corresponding package name in the standard input(*column 2*) if it finds then it grabs the corresponding line. And finally prints the value of (*column 3*) which was actually represents the package version.

```
$ dpkg -l
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
```

According to the above, column 2 represents the **package name**, column 3 represents the **package version**, column 4 represents the **architecture** and column 5 represents **package description**.

Comment: Why do you need to list *all* packages using `dpkg` first and then let awk filter them again? You can request the listing for a single package as well: `dpkg -l <package-name>`

Answer (score 0):

The command `apt -qq list <package-name>` shows whether the package is installed and appears to return the full version number.

#### Example 1 – uses `-qq`

```
$ apt -qq list network-manager
network-manager/now 1.10.14-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]
```

#### Example 2 – uses `-qq` and `*`

```
$ apt -qq list virtualbox-6*
virtualbox-6.0/unknown 6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~bionic amd64
virtualbox-6.1/unknown,now 6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~bionic amd64 [installed]
```

#### Example 3 – uses `-qqa`

```
$ apt -qqa list keepassxc
keepassxc/bionic,now 2.6.2-1ppa1~bionic1 amd64 [installed]
keepassxc/bionic 2.3.1+dfsg.1-1 amd64
```