# How can I find Boost version?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I just want to know how I can find the version of boost installed in my ubuntu 12.04? I am having trouble with the current precise and thinking of reverting back to 8.04. What is the boost version in 8.04?

Comment: What specific error are you having? You may find help for it at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 68):

The version of libboost on my 12.04 system is 1.48.0.2. Here's how you can find out:

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
```

- [How can I find the version number of an installed package via dpkg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15452/how-can-i-find-the-version-number-of-an-installed-package-via-dpkg)

Comment: This method work only if you installed it properly.  If you install the boost manually, you will get something like: dpkg-query: package 'libboost-dev' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Answer (score 26):

You can check `version.hpp` inside Boost include dir (normally `/usr/include/boost`, you can use `locate /boost/version.hpp` or similar to get that) for `BOOST_VERSION` or `BOOST_LIB_VERSION`.

```
$ cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"

//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_53"
```

SO: [How to determine the Boost version on a system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708706/how-to-determine-the-boost-version-on-a-system)

Comment: Also check `/usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp`. I found a higher version of boost there. 1_62 vs 1_58

Answer (score 2):

In the `C++` source file!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

int main() {
  std::cout << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << '\n';
}
```