# How do I check if I have a specific update for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

I recently reported a [bug on Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/1919008) and the fix was recently pushed as an update. One of the repo maintainers asked me to check if I have [this update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-autoar/0.2.3-2ubuntu0.2) installed or not.

How do I check if a particular update package has been installed in my system or not? Is there a way to check via the command line?

Comment: `dpkg -s <package> | grep version`

Comment: Though [`apt-cache policy`](https://askubuntu.com/a/15583/158442) might be better since it will also show whether that version is available for you install.

Comment: I would use `apt-cache policy`  (it also shows what is available as well from your available sources)